# Resources for Promotion/Demotion Strategies for ML Item Recommendation Systems?

Tags: machine-learning, e-commerce, recommendation-engine

We are looking to design a system where specific items or categories of items can be boosted/promoted up or relegated/demoted down the recommendation order.

What are the common strategies or standards to do such?

A cursory google search did not yield anything super-useful.
Though this seems like a common problem in e-commerce.
We are looking into Amazon Personalize on AWS as one option.

What is this area called in literature, is there standard name used in the field/industry?

Are there introductory or survey papers?